# bash: mysql: command not found

Tags: mysql, windows, git-bash

I just installed **MySQL** server and a **MySQL Workbench** on my new desktop and trying to use MySQL commands in **Git Bash**

to create some databases locally in folder

> C:\Users\OmNom\Desktop\code\burger\db

(*database file located in this folder*)

with

```
mysql -u root -p
```

but getting this message in return

```
bash: mysql: command not found
```

What am I doing wrong ? Do I have to install something else to make it work?

**P.S.** **OS Windows 10** , **Node.js** installed , server runs fine (I'm able to create databases in workbench).

**Please help!**

**P.P.S.** If you need additional information let me know!

Comment: Did you install the official installer for MySQL...can you please specify which version did you install it?

Comment: @Hackerman I've installed from official mysql website . It was MySQL Community Server >>>custom >>> mysql x64 5.7.10 && mysql workbench blah blah && mysql notifier && connector J 5.1 >>> created username && password .

Comment: @Hackerman I haven't installed utilities maybe that is a problem?

Comment: Try to use the `mysqlsh` instead

Comment: @Hackerman still getting the same thing. Maybe I should install mysql shell and utilities?

Comment: Or you can got to the folder `C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.7\bin` and look for the mysql.exe file...open a command line there and try the command there `mysql.exe -uroot -p`...if that works then you need to set the `path` environment variable in your windows machine in order to recognize the command from anywhere

Comment: @Hackerman yes it works , but how can I set the path environment variable? I'm sorry noob here...

Comment: I am on the bus now, I'll prepare a full answer as soon as I got home.

Comment: @Hackerman hey man I figured it out. Thanks for giving me an ideas how to solve it . Yes, the problem was in setting a path environment variable. I see that you are in top 4% stackoverflowers if you need some more reputation just write down the answer and I will mark it as solved. Thanks again!

Answer (score 13):

> That's because your MySQL bin program (mysql command tool) not added to
> your windows PATH system variable.

Now this can happen for several reasons, one particular reason could be your installation executable not run as administrator. So to use it with your git bash you can do two things.

**Approach 1**

Go to the bin directory of your MySQL installation using git bash. For example

```
$ cd 'C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.7\bin'
```

Then run

```
./mysql -u root -p
```

**Approach 2**

To make it easier to invoke MySQL programs, you can add the path name of the MySQL bin directory to your Windows system PATH environment variable. To do so follow the MySQL official documentation guideline from here

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-windows-excerpt/5.7/en/mysql-installation-windows-path.html

**After adding the PATH variable you need to restart your git bash.**

Now you'll able to run mysql command from anywhere using git bash.

Answer (score 5):

Copy the path to mysql.exe, and add it to your computer's `PATH` variable, then open git bash and type

```
winpty mysql -u root -p
```

Comment: This may also require restarting Windows in order for git bash to except the path updates.

Answer (score 5):

If everything has been followed by the book `mysql` wont work (as I have tried) but `mysqlsh` instead will do the work.

Answer (score 3):

Following steps installed drush in my windows 7 PC's & laptop seamlessly. Please ignore 1st two steps if you already have a web-server-stack running in your machine.

1. [Install VC11](https://download.microsoft.com/download/1/6/B/16B06F60-3B20-4FF2-B699-5E9B7962F9AE/VSU_4/vcredist_x86.exe)
2. Install [XAMPP-5.6-VC11](https://www.apachefriends.org/xampp-files/5.6.32/xampp-win32-5.6.32-0-VC11-installer.exe)
3. Install [GIT](http://git-scm.com/download/win)
4. Install [composer](https://getcomposer.org/Composer-Setup.exe)
5. Install drush using compser
   in git-bash type: composer global require drush/drush
6. in bash - navigate to sites folder
7. check environment by typing following commands in bash one by one

   ```
   php --version
   mysql --version
   composer --version
   drush --version
   ```

Incase any of the above commands returns error, make sure to update environment variables accordingly.

Make sure that your environment variables have these entries (depending upon your install location & user name)

```
C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Roaming\Composer\vendor\bin;
C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Roaming\Composer\vendor\drush\drush\;
C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\ProgramData\ComposerSetup\bin;
C:\xampp\mysql\bin;
C:\xampp\php;
```

8. Finally in `sites\defalut\settings.php` change the host from `localhost` to `127.0.0.1`

Hope this helps

Comment: System Variables or User variables?

Answer (score 2):

This error means that from some reason your shell doesn't recognize the mysql client. It might be one of the following:

1. You opened the shell before installing MySQL, so therefore the `PATH` variable isn't updated on that shell instance. To make sure this is not the case, close the shell and re-open it, try to use the command again.
2. From some reason the mysql client is not added to the `PATH` environment variable. Add the directory where mysql exists to the `PATH` variable using this command, and then try to run the client:

   ```
   set PATH=%PATH%;C:\xampp\php
   ```
3. Maybe you didn't install MySQL client and only installed the server? Can you find the executable somewhere on your computer?

Comment: 1. not a case for sure I reinstalled my PC after that few times 3. I don't have a client for sure (I will try to reinstall whole thing now). 2. Sorry I'm completely new to MySQL . 2.1 Can you give me more detailed instructions here. 2.2 Do I need to have a xampp installed ? I don't use php do I have to create the same path ? 2.3 What is the PATH variable and how and whre to add this command?

Answer (score 0):

**First make sure that you have installed all the required components.**

If not then uninstall the installer only and run installer again. Then install all components if you haven't already.

Now open `Windows Terminal` or `Command Prompt` and travel into `MySQL server 8.0`'s bin directory (i.e., `C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\bin`). Run

```
$ mysql -u root -p
Enter password:
```

and enter the root password

**If it works then the problem was in only PATH Variable/Environment Variable**

Add a new variable named `MYSQL_HOME` in `user variables` and give path of bin directory of MySQL Server as value in it and also in `path` variable

**Just restart your machine and it should work fine.**

Comment: You must install client and server module for MariaDB or MySQL.

If you want to use standard package for CentOS 7, it will use mariadb.

ex.
```Code:```
```# yum install mariadb-server```
```# systemctl start mariadb```
```# systemctl enable mariadb```

Answer (score 0):

put command $mysql -p
it's help to run the mysql and then it's put your password.I solved in mysql in docker case.So suggested to use your terminal.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).